# Dockerfile for angular-cli application returns ng: command not found

Tags: angular, docker, angular-cli

I am trying to run my Angular application (generated with the ng-cli) in a docker file.

This is my docker file:

```
FROM node:6.10.0

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install --dev && npm cache clean

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD [ "ng", "serve" ]
```

This however crashes with the command:

> ng: command not found

How is this possible? Angular CLI is listed in my development depencies of my package.json.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the command `ng` is not found in your `$PATH` variable. When you run `npm install --dev` it will install your dependencies within the scope of your project.

Commands invoked through the `scripts` property in you package.json will be able to find your local dependencies.

Example package.json:

```
{
  "name": "example-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Example package that starts ng",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6.10.0

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/ RUN npm install --dev && npm cache clean

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Note that npm supports only a handful of scripts out of the box. If you want run arbitrary scripts you use the `npm run-script ...` command.

```
...
"scripts" : {
   "ng-serve": "ng serve"
}
...
```

Run the script by calling: `npm run-script ng-serve`

You can find a complete list of default scripts and more information in the npm docs here: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts